# How to fill option set with system activity types?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

There are default activity types like:

- Task
- Appointment
- Phone call

etc ...

Is there any way I could fill option set with those? Do I need to use js sdk and odata to get that data?

I've already wasted few hours trying to achieve that, with no success. That's why Im asking here. Thanks

Comment: If you've already wasted a few hours trying to achieve filling an OptionSet with the names of activity types, I would suggest opting for manually adding them. There are only a few...But I might misunderstand your question completely, in which case you might consider elaborating on your question.

Comment: Are you trying to create activities of a certain type or add types to that optionset?

Answer (score 1):

Option Sets are metadata. You don't change them on the fly or inject them. They define the valid values for the attribute, this is why you will find the valid options in Xrm.Page.getAttribute().getOptions();
You can add or remove (from the valid options) those options which actually get displayed in the control using [Optionset control methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_options).

It is true that you can use the Optionset control methods to add arbitrary options, but you will get an error if you try to save the value. An option is just a { value:Number, text:String } object. So you can use the addOption method to add them - you just can't save the value. Use [setSubmitMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_setSubmitMode) to use 'never' so it doesn't get saved.

You can query the metadata to get the DisplayName of any entities that have EntityMetadata.IsActivity  == true, but this is an expensive operation to perform every time your form loads. You are probably better off configuring it manually.

Comment: hi Jim! Welcome to StackOverflow!